# Flutter background floating window feature

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to create a background floating window using Flutter like IMO does.

**Background Floating Window**: This is a window which can be dragged using fingers and it is not only limited to my app. User can have my app window showing up on different apps too. Some apps that uses it include TrueCaller, IMO, etc.

Here is the screenshot, the boy window can be dragged and when you tap home button, the app will get minimised but this boy window will still be there on the home launcher and if user navigates to some other app, this window will still persist.

#### Screenshot Example

[image]

Comment: People gave two answers based on the information you've provided and each time you've rejected them, then added criteria that you didn't mention before.

Don't assume people know what IMO is. Just say what you need, in detail.

The original question wasn't clear that the window had to remain after hitting the home button. And even after you added that, you rejected the next answer because the window can't be dragged... which you hadn't mentioned before either.

To get an answer that works, please be more specific... and have a great day!

Comment: @scottstoll2017 I really apologize for being unclear. Let me update my question. Sorry to all the folks if I had caused them any inconvenience.

Comment: No problem! Let's see if this gets you a useful answer faster!

Comment: I need Flutter floating window also. My requirement is to implement a floating clock. This clock should always be seen after switched to other apps.

Comment: What on earth is a “boy window”?

Answer (score 0):

the below code gives you the result you want

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Unit Converter',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 150,
                  height: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue
                  )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't answer the question. I am asking for Floating Window which can be dragged.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal E.g of What you Want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: App(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  Color caughtColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        DragBox(Offset(0.0, 0.0), 'Box One', Colors.blueAccent),
        DragBox(Offset(200.0, 0.0), 'Box Two', Colors.orange),
        DragBox(Offset(300.0, 0.0), 'Box Three', Colors.lightGreen),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DragBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Offset initPos;
  final String label;
  final Color itemColor;

  DragBox(this.initPos, this.label, this.itemColor);

  @override
  DragBoxState createState() => DragBoxState();
}

class DragBoxState extends State<DragBox> {
  Offset position = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = widget.initPos;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        left: position.dx,
        top: position.dy,
        child: Draggable(
          data: widget.itemColor,
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: widget.itemColor,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
            setState(() {
              position = offset;
            });
          },
          feedback: Container(
            width: 120.0,
            height: 120.0,
            color: widget.itemColor.withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I know `Draggable` and the question is somewhat different. I updated the question to add more detail. Sorry for being unclear in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time this question has been around, but in case there are still developers who are in a quest for the same thing, I found these two plugins which seem to be doing just that:

1. draggable window
2. will be visible over other applications even when your own app is in background
3. the "background" app can still communicate with that "floating window"

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_floatwing

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to do this would be a stack.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: First of all, it is better to write this answer as a comment, and second sorry this doesn't answer the question. I am asking for Floating window which can be shown even when you press home button from the app, not a normal stack.